# Javascript - Change height in <div style> depending on the height of image(s) in the div or completely remove it?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Well as the title says.
Right now each signature (on a forum) div got:

```
<div style='height:Xpx;overflow:scroll'> (X = depends on each signature due to the image heights shifting)
```

And I want to change the height so I don't have to scroll through each signature, but showing all images directly.
Here is the right part of a signature:

http://puu.sh/4xOW7.jpg (couldn't use the website-image-feature due to not having 10 rep)

And I tested around and managed to make it like this:

http://puu.sh/4xPar.jpg (it's much more further down)

and like this..

http://puu.sh/4xPco.jpg (couldn't post more than 2 links -_-)

I also tried to remove the overflow:scroll, change it, and so on. (also tried removing height: etc)
But I just can't get it to simply remove the scrollbar - making all images show normally. I'd really appreciate help! :)

Comment: why does the div need to have a fixed height?

Comment: It doesn't, all I want is the images to show properly.

Comment: oh ok then just set height on the div to auto; if you want it would also be helpful to see your css and html in a jsfiddle

Comment: If I put the height to auto, this is how it looks like: http://puu.sh/4xPFW.jpg
What I want is to be able to view everything inside the div without having to scroll. I dunno if I make any sense but if that is so, let me know and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Hm, it might be the parent container. It's hard to solve without the code. Could you please put it in a jsfiddle for me to see?

Comment: Isn't this from battlefield?

Comment: Also, have you tried making the div an `inline-block`

Comment: can you narrow your script down a little bit to just the problem

Comment: oh if its someone elses site then your only option would be to make the img {height:100%; width:auto;}

Comment: @ShalomAptekar http://puu.sh/4xQOz.png - It's the same with height = 100%. I'm using the jScript as an userscript (Greasemonkey). I don't know if I'm using the wrong div or something? :v

Comment: @GrantWeiss Well, http://pastebin.com/9Lzs74bJ - around here it should be I suppose.

Comment: <div style="height:250px;overflow: auto;">
I believe it's that line, but I'm not sure how I can change it as it does not have an class nor ID?

Comment: you could select .after_content > div or just set your image height to 250px

Comment: @ShalomAptekar If you mean I can use .after_content; I tried.
If you mean .after_content > div (?) then how would I do that?
Aaaaaand, well, as I stated it's on a forum that I want to be able to view all images without having to scroll each signature due to their images being too large for the set (250px) size.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `style="height:250px;overflow: auto;"`

you need `style="display:inline;"`

Comment: Hi and thanks, but I've tried that too. Depending on which of the divs around there, it just moves the signature box up and down. I need to edit the <div style='height:250px;overflow:auto;'> but as it does not have a id/class I'm unsure how I would do it. As I stated; it's not my site, I'm trying to use this as a userscript.

Comment: Well, I'm not able to edit the actual php/html/css file(s) as it's not my site. Hence why I'm using a userscript.
It looks like this: http://puu.sh/4xRU8.png (the class name I got there is one of the ones I've tried, i.e signaturecontainer etc)